# What is a better way to implement a filter in a list using Riverpod?

Tags: flutter, dart, state-management, riverpod

I need to use a `TextField` as a input to create a filter for a `List`. It should update the UI in realtime, but I haven't managed to do that yet.

By reading [how to combine provider states](https://riverpod.dev/docs/concepts/combining_providers), I tried to combine my provider for the `TextField`and the one that manages my `List`.

Without using `Timer? _debounceTimer`, my UI instantly updates whenever I type a single letter, and the `TextField` cleans itself.

By using `Timer? _debounceTimer`, I can get around the UI instantly updating, but it's not really realtime and the `TextField` still cleans itself.

Here is my code for the `Providers`:

```
final searchTextProvider = StateProvider<String>((ref) => '');

class ProductScreenNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<List<Product>> {
  Timer? _debounceTimer;

  Future<List<Product>> _fetchProducts() async {
    final filter = ref.watch(searchTextProvider);

    final allProducts = await ProductRepository.instance.getAll();
    if (filter.isNotEmpty) {
      return allProducts
          .where((product) =>
          product.name.toLowerCase().contains(filter.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    } else {
      return allProducts;
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<List<Product>> build() async {
    return _fetchProducts();
  }

  Future<void> addProduct(Product product) async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      await ProductRepository.instance.insert(product);
      return _fetchProducts();
    });
  }

  Future<void> deleteProduct(int id) async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async {
      await ProductRepository.instance.delete(id);
      return _fetchProducts();
    });
  }

  //This seems wrong, as I feel there should be no need for the DebounceTimer.
  void updateSearchText(String value) {
    _debounceTimer?.cancel();
    _debounceTimer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 500), () {
    ref.read(searchTextProvider.notifier).update((_) => value);
    _fetchProducts();
    });
  }
}

final asyncProductScreenProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider<ProductScreenNotifier, List<Product>>(() {
  return ProductScreenNotifier();
});
```

This is the code for the `TextField` that acts as the filter input:

```
 Widget searchProductField(WidgetRef ref) {
    return TextField(
      onChanged: (value) {
        ref.read(asyncProductScreenProvider.notifier).updateSearchText(value);
      },
      decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: "Pesquisar Produtos"),
    );
  }
```

If there is a need for the code of the body of the UI, I can also add it here, but I believe the problem is the way I'm combining these `Providers`.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your issue in code right now, but it doesn't seem like it has anything to do with the `DebounceTimer` – you are right that it's more likely related to how you're combining the states.

Obviously, you have two states, and one of them (the list of visible products) depends on another (the search text). With Riverpod, the dependency between different states (wrapped in providers) is established via the `ref.watch` alone, so you just don't need to update the search text provider from within the product list provider. In fact, by doing so your `searchTextProvider` seems to be re-initialized each time you try to update it (hence, the `TextField` cleans itself). Instead of this

> onChanged: (value) {
> ref.read(asyncProductScreenProvider.notifier).updateSearchText(value);
> }

try this

> onChanged: (value) {
> ref.read(searchTextProvider.notifier).state = value;
> }

This should work because the `asyncProductScreenProvider` is already subscribed to the `searchTextProvider` via `watch` and should be recomputed every time the search text changes. Also, I don't see why you need to use the notifier's `update` method here since your new state doesn't really depend on the previous one, so the normal `state = value` should be the way to go.

Comment: Ok, so I combined your solution and changed the `DebounceTimer` to happen inside `Widget searchProductField(WidgetRef ref)`. It works, but if I search for a product, it shows up, the UI gets refreshed and it cleans the `TextField` again. Would love for it to not get clean.